# Run php file after post_updated in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I wrote a PHP script to create and XML of all my WooCommerce products.
This runs every night via a cronjob and works fine. But I want it to run after `post_updated`, how can I manage to do this? Can't figure it out :(

```
function check_values(){
    //Here it needs to run the specific PHP file to create the new XML after for example updating the product price
}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the cron script to run every 10 minutes instead of once a day

At the beginning of your xml generation script put a check

```
$status = get_option( 'cron_job_xml' );

if($status != 'on') {
exit;   
} else {
update_option( 'cron_job_xml', 'off', 'no' );
}
```

And this code to functions.php

```
function check_values(){

update_option( 'cron_job_xml', 'on', 'no' );

}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 );
```

Now when we update the post, we will change the value of option
And the cron script will check the value and run only when there are updates.